# Creating a curved triangle arc in CSS

Tags: css

[image]

Is it possible to create a curved arc triangle-like thing with CSS? (Look at the blue area).

I can create this effect with one oval-shaped div that is white, and another div it sits on top of that is blue, so it gives the illusion of the arc. However that is no good because I need the transparency where the arc is at, as opposed to having a white area there blocked by the white oval.

I want to create either the whole, or halves that I can set next to each other to make a whole.

Comment: how about using an SVG graphic? SVG uses the same syntax as CSS

Comment: Hmm yeah I don't see why an SVG wouldn't work. But CSS would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a pseudo element that has the width of the parent and a predefined height.

On this, set border-radius 50% to make it elliptical, and add a shadow going upwards the will get your shape.

The base element needs to have overflow hidden to keep the shadow inside the rectangle

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(black, black);
  background-size: 100% 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  height: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px -80px 0px 100px blue;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for because it enables a transparency under the arc. Thanks.

Comment: Happy that it helped you !

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by applying a border top radius to a pseudo-element:

```css
div {
  background: blue;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Great, such a simple and clever way. Thanks!

Comment: On second look, this actually doesn't solve my problem because it gives the same effect as the solution in my question (the oval part is white, and I need it transparent). Adding a transparent color doesn't work because it inherits the color of the div it is a pseudo selector of.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that requirement.  I'll give it some thought, but it may not be possible using a single element.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend doing this with two SVGs. That way you won't experience stretching. Then you place on on either side of the page. Then they should responsively stretch.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="360px" height="288px" viewBox="0 0 360 288" style="enable-background:new 0 0 360 288;">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#03B3DB;}
  </style>
    <path class="st0" d="M91.7,109.1V78.6h190c0,0-38-0.4-104.9,7.4C117.7,92.9,91.7,109.1,91.7,109.1z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome SVG solution. Thanks!.